# Tkinter: How to run checks at predetermined intervals on if a file has been changed (outside of the mainloop())

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading

I am currently working on a programming project for my first year at university. I have developed the GUI and it's functionality using the python module tkinter just fine although I am having trouble with a certain aspect. It's a university chat server and at the moment I am developing a local machine only variation of the software, this means I am using text files within a /server directory in the program files and storing several plain text files with names relating to the server name it includes all the message logs of. So far my program successfully is able to take a users input and display it in the chat box and it updates on another instance of the software when said other piece of software sends a message - in short the software only updates the chat box when the user sends a new message.

I have been tinkering with ways to possibly run the 'updateChatBoxText' function alongside the GUI's mainloop function as just adding the updateChatBoxText function inside the GUI's mainloop and/or adding a while loop after/within the main loop does not achieve my goals. I have also experimented with multithreading and the 'threading' module in Python in order to theoretically run the function that is responsible for updating the chat in parallel with the functions (self-defined) which is drawing the GUI onto the screen. I have unfortunately tried many a thing and hope this community could help me shed some light on this issue. I link my entire programs code below.

```
from tkinter import *

def sendMessage():
    with open("servers/" + serverIDEntryBox.get() + ".txt", "a+") as log:
        log.write(usernameEntryBox.get() + ": " + messageEntryBox.get() + "\n")
    # THIS IS THE PART I WANT AUTOMATED EVERY COUPLE OF SECONDS
    if serverIDEntryBox.get() != "":
        with open("servers/" + serverIDEntryBox.get() + ".txt", "r") as log:
            chatBoxText.set(log.read())
            print("Chat updated")
    # THIS IS THE PART I WANT AUTOMATED EVERY COUPLE OF SECONDS

root = Tk()
root.title("NTU Chat Server - Local Machine Only")
root.geometry("900x900")
chatBoxText = StringVar()

configPanelFrame = Frame(root, bg = "#e069ab")
configPanelFrame.pack(fill=X)

usernameEntryLabel = Label(configPanelFrame, text = "Username:", font = "Candara 12", bg = "#e069ab", 
fg = "white")
usernameEntryLabel.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X)

usernameEntryBox = Entry(configPanelFrame)
usernameEntryBox.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=X)

serverIDEntryLabel = Label(configPanelFrame, text = "Server ID:", font = "Candara 12", bg="#e069ab", 
fg = "white")
serverIDEntryLabel.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X)

serverIDEntryBox = Entry(configPanelFrame)
serverIDEntryBox.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=X)

chatBoxLabel = Label(root, textvariable = chatBoxText, bg = "pink", font = "Candara 16", anchor = NW, 
justify = LEFT)
chatBoxLabel.pack(expand = TRUE, fill = BOTH)

messageEntryFrame = Frame(root)
messageEntryFrame.pack(fill = BOTH, anchor = S)

messageEntryBox = Entry(messageEntryFrame, font = "Candara 12")
messageEntryBox.pack(side = LEFT, fill = BOTH, expand = TRUE)

messageSendButton = Button(messageEntryFrame, text = "Send", command=sendMessage, font = "Candara 
12", bg="#e069ab", fg = "white")
messageSendButton.pack(expand = TRUE)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can schedule functions to be called after a specified delay by using the universal widget [`after()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) method. If you have the called function call `after()` itself, you can make these calls occur periodically.

Comment: ahh thank you very much, I added root.after(1000. updateChatBoxText) just before the root.mainloop() and it runs the function just when it needs although I am aiming to have this repeat, I have tried to put this is a if/while statement is make it repeat *every* second - how would I go about this?

Comment: Call `root.after(1000, updateChatBoxText)` at the end of `updateChatBoxText()`.

Comment: Do what @acw1668 said, which is what I meant about the called function itself calling `after()`.